Is there a complex that computes the crystalline cohomology groups of affine varieties?
Motivation: if $Y$ is a smooth affine algebraic variety over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, then the algebraic de Rham cohomology of $Y$ can be computed directly in terms of the differentials on $Y$, as the cohomology of the complex
$$
\mathcal{O}(Y) \to \Omega(Y) \to \wedge^2 \Omega(Y) \to \ldots.
$$
This "naive de Rham complex" doesn't work if $Y$ is projective, and the typical definition (at least if $Y$ is smooth) passes to hypercohomology. A theorem of Hartshorne says that this whole setup can instead be computed, and even generalized to the non-smooth case, in terms of a choice of formal completion of $Y$, and Grothendieck in turn removed the choice of formal completion from this approach by reintepreting Hartshorne's framework in terms of computing the cohomology of the constant sheaf on a site whose objects are something like every possible piece of data of $Y$ together with a nilpotent thickening.
Now, if $X$ is instead a (possibly not smooth, possibly not affine) scheme over a field of characteristic $p$, we have crystalline cohomology, which, inspired by the above result of Grothndieck, is defined in terms of the cohomology of a sheaf (maybe a special kind of sheaf called a crystal?) on a site of "divided-power thickenings," which are nilpotent embeddings together with a "divided-power structure" on the defining ideals.
The question: Divided power structures are pretty concrete, whereas sites obviously take the level of abstraction up a notch. I've never really gotten very far trying to understand crystalline cohomology, and I'd sort of like to learn these two ideas one at a time, and therefore to "see" divided power structures computing cohomology directly.
The hope is that if we restrict to the smooth, affine case (I'm also fine taking $k$ algebraically closed or $k$ finite if it helps simplify the homological algebra), there is a similar result to the characteristic $0$ case, where there's a straightforward complex (with divided powers presumably showing up) that computes the cohomology, functorially in the variety. Is that true, and if so, what is the complex?
(If it's not true, is there still something useful we can "see" in the affine case by playing with differential forms and divided power structures in a symbol-pushing way?)

shorter version of the question: write exactly this beautiful expository paper, but for crystalline cohomology :-)  https://swc-math.github.io/aws/2007/KedlayaNotes11Mar.pdf

Are you aware of this paper? https://public.websites.umich.edu/~bhattb/math/crystalline-comparison.pdf

@AlexYoucis I was not, thank you! Are you thinking the result I want comes from theorem 2.12? (Which crystal, equivalently which pair $(M, \nabla)$, do we want, to get the Weil cohomology theory -- (and what is a crystal)?) Do you think you can translate this for someone who doesn't speak sites or derived categories, and make that an answer?

(Even if you don't have the time to translate, please make it an answer, no point wasting the bounty.)

I gave this paper of Bhatt—de Jong only out of convenience, this is standard and in Berthelot—Ogus (in some form), and is on the stacks project, here: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07LE

The $(M,\nabla)$ you want to take here is the ‘trivial one’ as your $\mathcal{F}$ is, in this case, the structure sheaf. A crystal is just a quasi-coherent sheaf on the ringed site $((S/\Sigma)\mathrm{crys},\mathcal{O}{(S/\Sigma)\mathrm{crys}})$ — as in it’s locally the cokernel of free $\mathcal{O}{(S/\Sigma)_\mathrm{crys}})$-modules. They are the ‘coefficients’ for crystalline cohomology.

By the way, I forgot to mention that if you find these references daunting, there is a much more gentle, detailed explanation of the explicitly isomorphism you want in this master’s thesis (it’s the point of the whole thing, and done ind §5): https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/w.h.rienks/thesis.pdf

@AlexYoucis Thanks for all these references! I skimmed Berthelot-Ogus a long time ago, and the write-up in this question is basically what I remember of it.
The content of the question is: in the affine case, define crystalline cohomology without sites, e.g. well enough that one could compute the crystalline cohomology of an elliptic curve over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$. I do believe this should be possible in terms of Theorem 2.12.
(In other words, my goal is not to understand crystalline cohomology in generality, it is to understand divided powers in a site-free context.)

Then I would look at that last reference I sent, and the notion of what he calls ‘PD-de Rham cohomology’.
